# Multithreading compile issue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I am write a subclass of UITableViewCell to loading some image from internet but when using dispatch_async it won't work [imageUITableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2S8p.png)

class imageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell

```
private func updateCell() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
}
}
```

error: cannot convert value of type 'qos_class_t' to expected argument type 'Int' 
fix-it replace "QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED" with Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED)

can't figure out why,any idea will be appreciate

Comment: What wrong with that ? just replace it and then see what it wanted here!

Comment: You have to tell us more. What's not working? Do you have any error after or before compilation? Show some code.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra after replace four times it still won't compile and Xcode give up

Comment: @MichałKwiecień the code and compiler error are posted on picture just click the imageTableViewCell, I will post the text version asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    //fetch something
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //update UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of your answer.